# Is there a system that generates ID strings for the purpose of high probability error correction with minimal length?

Tags: algorithm

I need a system that generates IDs to be printed, sent out, and later reentered into our database. The forms are usually faxed in and out and therefor some fidelity is lost. I need the IDs to be as short as possible to minimize the work to be done manually reentering them, but they need to be unique enough to allow for automatic error correction.

I have worked with fuzzy search before and understand the concept of probabilistic matching, but not with unique IDs that I am generating for that purpose.

Edit: I think that several of you had a very good point about the QR code which has very robust error correction built in. Eventually, we will move to that type of solution, but for now, the IDs need to be human readable.

Yes, they could simply be printed bigger, or multiple times on different parts of the paper. However, that is not the solution that I have been asked to research/develop and it does not handle human error when typing in the code.

Comment: Can you simply "print" them larger so that loss of fidelity is not a problem?

Comment: Search for "error correcting codes". You have to trade off the error correction capabilities and the length of the code.

Comment: If they're just going to be printed out and scanned/faxed back in again, why not use QR codes? (Are people still using fax machines out there??)

Answer (score 1):

1. Firs, of course, I suggest you to use bar-code or qr-code, if you print your form yourself.
2. If [1] is not possible - I suggest you select from alphabet special subset of character, aren't like each to others in drawing - it will decrease error probability after scanning.
   For example, for numbers 0-9 lets you use ABCEHJKLNO; There is removed 
   D->C, F->E, G->C, I->J, M->H; And, when you receive "M" - convert it to "H", and so on. This is simple "OCR error correction code".
3. Add one char = checksum. This is some "hash(ID) % 10" for base 10 numbers.

Comment: In fact, for #1, you can buy a barcode scanner for less than $50 that automatically reads the barcode and inputs that into a form field.  You can actually program them to hit TAB or ENTER.